# Create a table of points that intersect with polygons in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, intersection, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I have a set of polygon and point data.  Each polygon shares the same area with dozens of points.  I want to create a table that shows which points intersect with which polygon.  What is the best tool in ArcGIS Pro to produce this?

Comment: For example Intersect

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the Spatial Join geoprocessing tool. The target layer is the point feature class, while the join layer is your polygons. The output will be the set of points with a new field containing the ObjectIDs or some other attribute from the intersecting polygons.